# Vb.net - error sending a mail period of time, or established

Tags: vb.net, smtpclient

Hey i am trying to send a file using vb.net in gmail.com, but the problem is i am getting an error "period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 64.233.166.108:567"

I am not sure what the problem si and i couldn't find an answer to it anywhere :(

Thanks for the help!

Code:

```
 Using mail As New MailMessage
            mail.From = New MailAddress("....@gmail.com")
            mail.To.Add("........@gmail.com")
            mail.Body = "Computer info Below"
            Path = "C:\Users\" & Environment.UserName & "\Pictures\hello.txt"
            Dim attach As New Attachment(Path)
            mail.Attachments.Add(attach)
            mail.Subject = Environment.UserName
            mail.Priority = mail.Priority.Normal
            Using SMTP As New SmtpClient
                SMTP.EnableSsl = True
                SMTP.Port = "567"
                SMTP.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
                SMTP.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("....@gmail.com", "******")
                SMTP.Send(mail)
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: Are you sure about that Port? Give Port 587 a chance :)

Comment: I think the gmail ssl smtp port is 465

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure about that Port? Give Port 587 a chance :) – [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi)

Solved